# Isomorphism between curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Fix a number field $k$ and a smooth projective curve $C$ defined over $k$. If $p_1,p_2$ are two distinct closed points on $C$, is $C\backslash \{p_1\}$ isomorphic to $C \backslash \{p_2\}$?

I know this is true if $C = \mathbb{P}^1_k$, since by removing a point we can find an invertible $2$-by-$2$ matrix that sends the point to the point at infinity, hence we get $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ no matter what point we remove. Based on this, I would think the above would be true, but must the degree of the points be the same, i.e., do we need the degree of the field extensions $\kappa(p_i)/k$ for $i=1,2$ to be equal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens iff there's an automorphism of $C$ interchanging $p_1$ and $p_2$: the rational maps $C\to C$ coming from the isomorphism $C\setminus\{p_1\}\cong C\setminus\{p_2\}$ extend to regular maps $C\to C$ which are still mutually inverse. In particular, $p_1$ and $p_2$ must have the same residue field (and this is sufficient for the case of $\Bbb P^1$). For curves of general type, this dramatically constraints the possible pairs of points - any $p_1$ has only finitely many $p_2$ that can be exchanged with it since $C$ has only finitely many automorphisms.

Comment: They need to have the same residue field because an isomorphism $C \rightarrow C$  sending $p_1$ to $p_2$ induces the isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_{C,p_1} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{C,p_2}$ of local rings, am I right?

Comment: When I saw this question I initially guessed that the answer depends on the genus. But I was thinking that it would hold for elliptic curves as well. After all the group structure gives us translations?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen do you mean the sufficiency statement? I guess I forgot to write anything about genus 1 curves.

Comment: @KelvinLian yes, that's correct.

Comment: @KReiser Actually when I asked this question I had the elliptic curves in mind, because there's a [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4361314/what-happens-to-an-elliptic-curve-if-a-different-base-point-is-specified) and an answer about changing the base point.